# Low frame rate while using Yolov8 object segmentation

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, frame-rate, roboflow

I have trained a yolov8 model on colab and export the best.pt and i wanted to using it for my webcam:

```
from ultralytics import YOLO
from ultralytics.yolo.v8.detect.predict import DetectionPredictor
import cv2
model = YOLO("best.pt")
model.predict(source="0", show=True, conf=0.5)
```

When i run the file it only have like 1 fps. How do i fix this?

I have tried to lower the resolution and change the camera but it still have that issue.

Comment: Can you post more about your system? What kind of GPU?

Comment: Echoing the above, what is your CPU and GPU like on your system?Also, what YOLO model size did you use for training? N, S, M, L, or X?